# How to kill watch command after certain time or set timeout for a watch command in bash

Tags: bash, watch

I am trying to watch (every second) the commit history of a file in github and see if the date object in the commit history changes. If the commit date changes within 30 seconds of watch, I want to stop watching and echo "change encountered" else I want to stop watching and echo "I have watched for 30 sec and no change was encountered. I am tired of looking!".

variables used

- *$myPGREADMECommitHist* consists of the URL I am trying to access
- *$mytoken* contains the token to grant access to URL.

Below watch command works but have to be killed manually (ctrl + c)

watch -n 1 "curl -H \"Authorization: token $mytoken\" \"$myPGREADMECommitHist\" > challenge1CommitObj.json && jq '.[0].commit.author.date' challenge1CommitObj.json > challenge1Output.txt && cat challenge1Output.txt"

I have tried using sudo kill command after my watch command which doesn't work
sudo kill -9 -INT $(pidof watch)

I have also tried timeout command along with watch command which doesn't work
timeout 10s watch...

I have tried do while with sleep command which works but I still want to see if watch command can be killed after certain time or be killed once a change is encountered within a certain time.

Comment: Sounds like you would be better of using `for i in {1..30}; do ... sleep 1; done` instead of `watch`.

Answer (score 8):

You could prepend `timeout` (from the `coreutils` package) to your oneliner:
`timeout 30 watch -n 1 -g -x date "+%F %R" && echo "Time changed" || echo "Timeout"`

This will kill `watch` after 30 seconds and exit non-zero making the second `echo` to run. 

If `watch` exits first (with `-g`) the exit status is `0` and the first `echo` runs.

Just replace `date` with your git command

A more verbose script or something like the solution @Socowi proposed is probable more fitting though.